# excluding from result something that is in a subquery result in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, subquery

is it posible to not show something in the result that is in a subquery.

example:
table1: has 4 numbers, 1,2,3,4.
so select * from table1 shows 4 result

is it posible to make :

```
    select * from table1 where not exists(select * from table1 where num = 3)
```

so the result would be 1,2,4. basically delete from the result something that is in the result of the subquery.

i know exists doesnt work for that as it only gives true false, but any other means?

thank you to everyone.

Comment: In this example, `select * from table1 where num <> 3` would do the trick.

Comment: @Matt, but the answer is: it is possible ;)

Comment: @arnoudhgz True, but "yes" is too short of an answer to leave. :-)

Comment: @vexen If it's a matter of comparing values from different tables, you're going to need an `JOIN`. [This chart](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_gWQaU40PH24/TG_d4LWGqYI/AAAAAAAAI0I/szwmLmy2t44/s640/Visual_SQL_JOINS_V2.png) gets the concept across pretty clearly.

Comment: @Matt i know that i would need a JOIN statement for a more complex query its just that in my real query i was trying to exclude some persons and only in some cases. next is the real query =) that now is working ......

        SELECT distinct id,nombre, apellido1,apellido2, personas.seccion from personas
      LEFT JOIN votaciones on personas.id = votaciones.id_persona 
       WHERE personas.seccion = 1 AND mesa = 'A' 
        AND (id_eleccion IS NULL OR id 
         NOT IN (SELECT id FROM personas JOIN votaciones ON personas.id = votaciones.id_persona WHERE id_eleccion =1))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`select * from table1 where num <> 3;`?

OR

`select * from table1 where id NOT IN (select id from table2 where num = 3);`

Elaborate more what you want.

Comment: Thank you, i think i tried that with select * in subquery thats why it didnt work.

Comment: yes thankyou it worked perfectly as planned, just silly me not knowing mysql too well to think of it for myself =)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT IN`, but the subquery must return only one column (same thing goes with exists I think). Something like this :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 NOT IN (SELECT column1 FROM table WHERE column2 = 3)
```

Comment: `NOT IN` causes a slower query then the not exists statement!

Comment: thx, that was the problem when i tried that i used selec * from in the subquery , thx for explaining that i need to use 1 column only.

Comment: You are welcome :)
You did not say that you were getting an error ;)

Comment: I think with not exist it isnt posible to exclude something becouse exists doesnt result in columns it gives true or false as a result if im not mistaking.

Comment: i didnt have an error it was just giving me 0 columns or didnt exclude that.